# Iphone first view noobie question

Tags: iphone, view

I got to change the first view of my iphone first project, i tried to change it in the app delegate but something is not working. What I got to do exactly? Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok what error you are getting when you run the application.more over  try to create the instance of viewcontroller1 in app delegate and add it to window,it works.`

Comment: I did that but the first view remain teh old one, and I think that is due to an IB error because I dont get anithing wrong execpt a worning on ib

Comment: "Warning: File's Owner, id -1. Outlet Unavailable; The 'view' outlet of 'File's Owner' is connected to 'View' but 'view' is no longer defined on NewViewController." this is it

Comment: ok then instead of navigating to the old view you just need to navigate to the new view?am i right?if so create the instance of the new view controller and map it in the ib or else you can acheive this programmatically with out using ib.